# WordPress 4.5.2: Uncaught ReferenceError: JQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Why my code is unable to run and brower's console is producing error "JQuery is not defined" even though I am en-queuing my JavaScript file into the plugin properly.

As per source code, JQuery Library file before is also importing before my JavaScript file.

Please take a look at the code below and let me know if I am doing something wrong:

File Path: wp-content/plugins/AjaxTest/AjaxTest.php

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Ajax Test
Description: This is a Ajax Test plugin
Version: 1.0
*/

function add_ajax_file()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-test', plugins_url('/js/ajax.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_ajax_file');
```

File Path: wp-content/plugins/AjaxTest/js/ajax.js

```
JQuery(document).ready( function($){

    alert("Hello");
});
```

Error Message in Console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: JQuery is not defined
(anonymous function)    @   ajax.js?ver=4.5.2:1
```

Order of JavaScript files in source code after running above code into the browser:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress1/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress1/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress1/wp-content/plugins/AjaxTest/js/ajax.js?ver=4.5.2'></script>
```

As suggested on web from WordPress users with similar problem, I have already tired adding below code into the wp-config.php file but no luck

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

I am using WordPress 4.5.2

Comment: It should be `jQuery`, not `JQuery`. Capitalization matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to correct this `JQuery` to `jQuery`

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){

    alert("Hello");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Hemnath! I was making a stupid mistake and wasted a lot of time

Answer (score 2):

you can use dollar sign in stead of jQuery for simplicity (if letter casing is hard for you to memorize). 
note: JavaScript (jQuery is a library built using JavaScript) is case sensitive.

the correct code would look like :

```
$(document).ready( function($)
```

Comment: Note: jQuery isn't *based* on JavaScript. It *is* JavaScript. Don't mistake them for two separate things.

Comment: well, correct me if I'm wrong, it's a library built using JavaScript, that's what I meant by based on JavaScript

Comment: You're right that it's built in JavaScript but when you write code using jQuery, you're writing JavaScript. jQuery isn't a separate language. It's just a library to be used with a certain language.

Comment: I've edited my answer to prevent confusion. thanks for making answer clearer.